# Declaring an object property in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to declare & instantiate a property that is of a object type, like so:

```
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('acc') accCanvas;
  @ViewChild('gyro') gyroCanvas;

  charts: {
    accChart: any ,
    gyroChart: any ,
  }; // problem
  acc: any;  // latest accelerometer data
  gyro: any; // latest gyro data
  logState: string = 'Start'; // button state
  stateColor: string = 'primary'; // button color
  logs: any[] = []; // will hold history of acc + gyr data
```

All the variables like acc, gyro etc work well and I can reference them as `this.xxxx` in my functions. However, I can't refer to `this.charts.accChart` or `this.charts.gyroChart` - they return as undefined. Can anyone please advise on how to declare and initialize the charts object property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`charts: { accChart: any, gyroChart: any }` is just a type declaration. It describes the shape of the `charts` member. If you like to immediately access its children, you need to initialize it:

```
charts: {
  accChart: any,
  gyroChart: any
} = {
  accChart: void 0, // or choose an initial value other than undefined
  gyroChart: void 0 // or choose an initial value other than undefined
};
```

Try to avoid the `any` type whenever possible. Use TypeScript's types, your own types or library typings instead.